# Конвертировать строку в список

Tags: python, список

Есть такая строка: `['Текст 1', 'Текст2']`

Как её конвертировать в список?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это строка? Похоже на список. Узнайте через type() - строка это или список

Comment: Да,это точно строка
(Она получается после конвертации json и еще нескольких манипуляций)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверняка дубликат, но лень искать. Обычно делается через `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

s = "['Текст 1', 'Текст2']"
lst = literal_eval(s)
print(type(lst), lst)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'list'> ['Текст 1', 'Текст2']
```